# Guzzle hangs communicating two apis

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, guzzle

in my application I have two laravel 5.2 servers running and they need to interact with each other to get resources using guzzle.

In my server 1, I use League Transformer to return some data, but the data needs to include a resource from my server 2
I get the data using guzzle in the transform function:

```
public function transform(MyModel $model) {

        $client = new Client();
        $result = $client->request('GET', 'localhost:8000/api/companies/'.$model->company_id);
        $company= $result->getBody()->getContents();

        $data = [
        'id' => (int) $model->id,
        'name' => $model->name,
        'status' => $model->status,
        ];

        $data['company'] = json_decode($company);
        return $data;
    }
```

When I make a request to get this resource to `localhost:4040/api/models/1`
I get this response:

```
"data": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "status": "active",
    "company": {
        "data": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "My Company",
        }
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is when I need to access MyModel (stored in server 1) from server 2 using guzzle, because I need to make a request to server 1:

```
$result = $client->request('GET', 'localhost:4040/api/models/'.$model->_id);
```

and server 1 needs to make a request to server 2 (in the transformer) to get the company.
This makes the client to wait forever and never get a response. I tried using Async request, but I get an empty response, and if I force the promise to wait, it also hangs forever.

Answer (score 1):

Do you run your apps locally using PHP's integrated web server? If yes, then this is the issue.

PHP's integrated web server can handle only one request simultaneously. You get a kind of deadlock on

> and server 1 needs to make a request to server 2

Try to run both server 1 and 2 on Apache/nginx/...